# quickly finding the moments of a numerically-defined PDF

Tags: density-function, numerical-integration

I have a two-dimensional continuous PDF which is numerically defined. From this PDF I would like to extract the second central moment (variance) of a "slice" of this distribution.

The "slice" is to be taken at a particular value on one of the axes (the slice is orthogonal to one axis).

What I am currently doing is:

1. identify the slice and numerically integrate over the support (or approximately so) of the function to get a normalization factor.
2. multiply the numerically-defined "slice" (which is a 1D pdf when I divide by the normalization factor) by the first power of the random variable and integrate to get the first moment (mean)
3. do that again with the second power to get the value $\langle x^2 \rangle$.
4. put those together to construct the second central moment.

Is there a method that one would expect to be generically faster than this method? I would like to know that before optimizing what I have too deeply.

=====On the possible optimizations=====

For the current procedure I already know that the mean actually may not have to be calculated that way (because of how the initial 2D distribution is constructed) and similarly for the normalization. The value of $\langle x^2 \rangle$ does not have any similar obvious optimizations, so, failing a new and generically faster method, the smaller step of optimizing this particular calculation would help.

Comment: The way you propose to calculate variance is numerically unstable. If the standard deviation is small compared to the mean, you'll get [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) (potentially extreme loss of accuracy).

Comment: @Glen_b thanks, that's a good point. I suppose since I have information about the mean I could do a change of variable and subtract it to be sure that condition is never met. I'm not sure if I can guarantee being able to do that correction to a good enough accuracy, but would that work? I should probably mention that I know the distribution is smooth and not highly pathological.

Comment: Smoothness and "niceness" won't solve the numerical stability problem, sorry. You can make it as nice as you like and still have the issue. However a simple shift of location can make a substantial difference (you don't have to mean correct, as long as you shift by a number not too any sd's away from the mean), i.e. integrate $(x-m)^2\cdot f(x)$ for any suitably nearby $m$ and also correct the mean in the $-\mu^2$ term by the same quantity.